# Is there any difference between the Sony A65 and A55 other than megapixels?

Tags: sony, megapixels, slt

When I look at dpreview's [side-by-side camera comparison](http://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/side-by-side?products=sony_slta65&products=sony_slta55) page, there is no difference between two cameras except pixel count (**24MP** vs. **16MP**).

If that's the only difference then $200 isn't worth it for just more pixels, because I don't need them. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can a spot a few differences; 24 fps video vs 30, more WB settings, different battery (longer lasting), heavier and bigger but thinner body (probably easier to hold), extra connectivity options, ±5 EV (at 1/3 EV steps) as oppose to ±2 EV (at 1/3 EV steps), AE bracketing option.

The Sony SLT A77 seems like a better alternative though.

Comment: Is 24fps a big deal?

Comment: it is if you do video. 24fps has a real cinematic feel.

Comment: Well, technically 24fps at 1/48th shutter speed is cinema.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the heating problem in A55 is a little troublesome. Plus the short battery life. It takes me almost 5 hours to charge but less than 2 hours to use it up full. But taking all this into consideration I have my doubts to put in so much extra for an A65.

Comment: Does the A65 fix these issues?